# Unable to bind to the hyperlink

Tags: asp.net

```
   <asp:HyperLink id=HyperLink1 
         Text='<%# Bind("report.reportId.ToString()") %>'       
         NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("~/manage.aspx") %>' 
         runat="server" />
```

I´m unable to run create this hyperlink as it gives me an error saying "A call to Bind was not well formatted.  Please refer to documentation for the correct parameters to Bind."

Comment: Not all control properties support using binding expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is *simple* data binding (no such data control is used) then use binding expression -  `<%# Expression %>`. (I presume that the `report.reportid` is public)

```
 <asp:HyperLink 
         id=HyperLink1 
         Text='<%# report.reportId %>'       
         NavigateUrl="~/manage.aspx" 
         runat="server" />
```

and call the DataBind() method from code-behind,

```
public void page_load() { 
  DataBind();
}
```